# Working LDIF configuration example for openLDAP SQL backend

Tags: openldap

I need to provide access to a postgres database through LDAP and I am looking for a working configuration sample using LDIF files.
All the examples I can find are using the old `slapd.conf` file for configuration.

I have loaded the sample tables from openldap in postgresql and configured unixodbc. I can access the database using `isql`.

I loaded the `back_sql` module and this seems to work.

However, when I try to add a database I get the error:

```
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: <olcDbPass> failed startup
```

and I have no idea what it means.

I am trying to `ldapadd`

```
dn: olcDatabase=sql,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcSqlConfig
olcSuffix: dc=test
olcDatabase: sql
olcDbName: ldap
olcDbPass: ldap
olcDbUser: ldap
```

which I think is correct but a proper configuration sample for the sql backend would be handy. What am I doing wrong or does anyone have a proper configuration sample?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the error to a buggy version of openldap on Ubuntu LTS with no newer versions available.
Using the latest openldap solved this problem.